# Starting points for REST API Automation

Tags: automated-testing, rest-api

I am new to REST API Automation.

As an Automation Engineer, should I expect to get the below mentioned things as a starting point which can help me write the automation code or is it my responsibility to figure out these -

1. API endpoints with expected inputs and outputs as part of basic documentation to understand the API's.
2. Test Cases that need to be automated.

I would like to understand what a standard approach and process might be, and if a standard process is followed across organizations.

Comment: Editing and reopening - I think there is a great deal of potential value in this question

Answer (score 2):

First off, welcome to SQA!

> I just want to understand how is standard approach and process which is followed across organizations.

To be blunt, there is *no standard for this*.  Organizations/companies define the process as they go.  When something doesn't work or isn't streamlined well-enough, you try something new.

> 1. REST URI's with expected inputs and outputs / basic documentation to understand the API's.
> 2. Test Cases that need to be automated.

You will absolutely need number 1!  `RESTful` services don't have a `WSDL`, like a `SOAP`-based `API` does.  As for number 2, this is also, a "yes".  You cannot automate what you do not understand.

If it were me, I would consider getting some tests running in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).  It is very easy-to-use and would get you up-and-running much more quickly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We had to create a API which provides Data based on a ISO-Norm. This API respone with a XML-Format & we are running automated Tests using XML-Schema-Files. So we validiate our API based on the XML-Schema which is offered by the ISO. 
For example: https://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3/AverageDailyEngineLoadFactor.xsd
We download this .xsd file and validate our xml-respone based on the .xsd and so we can say it is okay or not ok

Hope this helps a little bit!